# FFMPEG upgrade and install new dependencies

Tags: linux, video, codec

I am creating a website that needs to stream videos, and videos must be compatible with most of device(Iphone, Ipad, Android...). I am using Kaltura HTML5 player, but for that i need to convert the videos for 3 diferent formts: WebM/VP8, OGG/Theora, MP4/h264. Previous i was using FFMPEG to convert the videos from avi|wmv|flv|mpg to FLV.

I found a nice article explaining how i can create a new install of this, but as i already have the FFMPEG installed, i would like to know if there are the option to upgrade FFMPEG without a new installation(i tried to search on google but with no results :( ), and keep the same config from the previous one? And also how i can add the new dependencies to allow me to convert the videos to the 3 diferent formats that i mentioned above. This are the dependencies needed: orbis, x264, faac, theora, vpx. This article has a good explanation if you want to have a look: http://paulrouget.com/e/converttohtml5video/

Thanks
Bruno Fernandes

Answer (score 0):

The best way to maintain an `ffmpeg` configuration from one build to the next is to keep the `git` checkout directory around. When you do a `git pull` to upgrade your checkout to the latest, you can simply say `make` to build with the same settings as before.

If you still have your `ffmpeg` source tree but it wasn't checked out from the current `git` repo, you may be able to do a clean checkout, then lay it over the top of the old tree like this:

```
$ cd parent/of/old/ffmpeg/tree
$ git clone git://git.videolan.org/ffmpeg.git ffmpeg-temp
$ cd ffmpeg-temp
$ find | cpio -pud ../ffmpeg
$ cd ../ffmpeg
$ make
```

At that point, it should auto-reconfigure and build, unless the difference between the two versions is so large it requires manual intervention to reconfigure.

Lacking the source tree used to build it, I don't know an easy way to recover the `configure` options you used to build your existing `ffmpeg` binary.

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely too late for you.  But for people who might stumble upon this in the future, running the following will give you details of the current configuration:

```
ffmpeg -version
```

Here is a sample output, which shows the external libraries and configurations for the install.

```
ffmpeg version 1.0 Copyright (c) 2000-2012 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Nov  6 2012 23:14:41 with llvm-gcc 4.2.1 (LLVM build 2336.1.00)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-nonfree --enable-postproc --enable-libaacplus --enable-libass --enable-libfaac --enable-libfdk-aac 
  libavutil      51. 73.101 / 51. 73.101
  libavcodec     54. 59.100 / 54. 59.100
  libavformat    54. 29.104 / 54. 29.104
  libavdevice    54.  2.101 / 54.  2.101
```